# Linear Algebra Problem: projection matrix of eigenvector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

I need to solve a problem about projection matrix and eigenspace
Below is the problem:

We have matrix

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&0&2\\0&2&0\end{pmatrix}$

​
Find projection matrix toward eigenvector space of A(vector space which consists of eigenvector basis).

I tried to figure out what projection matrix was.
First I got eigenvalues of -2 and 2.

Should I calculate

P=A(ATA)−1AT

twice to get projection matrix of eigenspace when eigenvalue =-2
and when eigenvalue=2

I will be grateful if someone help me find what is projection matrix of eigenvector space of A.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenspace associated with $-2$ is $1$-dimensional, and the eigenspace associated with $2$ is $2$-dimensional.  The first of these projectors is easy to calculate; all we need is a single eigenvector In this case, you should find that an eigenvector of $-2$ is given by
$$
x = (0,1,-1)^\top.
$$
Now, we just need the associated projection matrix, $\frac{xx^\top}{x^\top x}$.

For the second of these, we want a basis for the kernel of
$$
A - 2I = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&-2&2\\0&2&-2}.
$$
If you solve this via row reduction (or just "by inspection"), you end up with the eigenvectors
$$
x_1 = (1,0,0)^\top, \quad x_2 = (0,1,1)^\top.
$$
You could now take these to be the columns of a matrix $M$ and compute and compute the projection $P = M(M^\top M)M^\top$, but because this is already an orthogonal basis we can deduce that the projection matrix is simply the sum of the individual associated projection matrices, namely
$$
P = \frac{x_1x_1^\top}{x_1^\top x_1} + \frac{x_2x_2^\top}{x_2^\top x_2} = 
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} + \frac 12\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&1&1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I calculated Projection matrix. When eigenvalue is -2,  P=1/2 * (0 0 0)(0 1 -1)(0 -1 1) right? ( ) ( ) () are rows

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Thank you sir! I have last question : I learned when B=M-1AM the eigenvectors of B equlas M-1x( x is eigenvector of A). My question is if B=MAM-1 does the eigenvectors of B become Mx or should I inverse MAM-1 to make M-1A-1M to get eigenvectors of B?

Comment: If $B = MAM^{-1}$ and $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $Mx$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

Comment: Thank you you are my savior, I will upvote anytime I see you in MSE thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I can't understand why Mx is an eigenvector of B when B=MAM-1... Cause my textbook only talks about M-1AM

Comment: @Korea19800 First of all, you could see for yourself:
$$
(MAM^{-1})(Mx) = MA(M^{-1}M)x = M(Ax) = M(\lambda x) = \lambda (Mx).
$$
Second, we could apply the textbook's statement noting that if $B = (M^{-1})^{-1}A(M^{-1})$ and $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $(M^{-1})^{-1}x$ will be an eigenvector of $B$.